# How to import modules in same directory between different packages

Tags: python-3.x

I am not able to import certain files/classes

My directory structure is below:

```
Main Project Directory
├── config
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── constants.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── utils
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── logger_config.py
    ├── sql_helper.py
    ├── update_data_on_request.py
    └── utility_functions.py
```

I want to import config.py from config into utility_functions.
Currently **init**.py is blank.
Error I face was `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'`

Comment: How did you import? `from config import config`

Comment: Yes, I imported like that

Comment: I even tried from config.config import DevelopmentConfig, but that too did not work

Comment: If you are trying to run a script inside "utils" modules inside "config" are not discoverable, since python automatically adds only the folder inside your `__main__` folder to path. Try running you main script from inside "Main Project Directory"

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `from config.config import *` in `utility_functions.py`

Comment: Yes I am using like this now. Error comes when I try to run some script from another folder, running main scripts from root directory does not causes any issue to me. lets say from above tree, If I run update_data_on_request.py, then it will say certain modules were not found